# Automatically update component for changes in ember.js service (ember 2.12)

Tags: ember.js

I have a service like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
     total: '',

    setTotal(total) {
        this.set('total', total);
    },
    getTotal(){
        return this.get('total');
    }
});
```

and two components in **difference routes**.

when one component update the "total" property in service, I want to automatically update the new value to other component's .hbs file. what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter whether two components are in different routes or not. You can just inject your service in both of the components and update value in one and reflect the change in the other via defining a computed property.

Please see the [following twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f1b8dc7560f8968353e8a9c10ec5ce0d?openFiles=twiddle.json%2Ctemplates.components.second-component.hbs) to see what I mean. `my-service` is injected into `first-component` and total value is set via `setTotal` upon action handling via button click. The change in `total` value of service is reflected to `second-component` thanks to `serviceTotal` computed property defined.

Comment: Works Grate. This is I was looking for thank you very much.!